# for loop with if else not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to make a list where users can insert their favourite beer. there have to be a check if the "userinput" is already in the array..
My thoughts were as follows: loop through the beersArray and check if there is a value in the array that is the same as what user puts in. If there is, alert and do not add. If not, then add the user input to a list item.

```js
var submitBier = document.getElementById("submitbeer");
submitBier.addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var beersArray = [];
    var beer = document.getElementById("favobeer");
    var beerList = document.getElementById("listwithbeer");
    var beerLi = document.createElement("LI");
    var BeerName = document.createTextNode(beer.value);

    var i;
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < beersArray.length; j++) {
        if (beersArray[j] === beer.value) {
            alert("This beer is already in the list");
        } else {

            for (i = 0; i < beersArray.length; i++) {
                beersArray[i].className = 'beer';
                beerLi.appendChild(BeerName);
                beerList.appendChild(beerLi);
                beersArray.push(beerList.appendChild(beerLi));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="beers">
    <h1 id="vraagnaam">add your favourite beers</h1>
    <input type="text" id="favobeer"  value = "" />
    <button id="submitbeer" type="submit" value="Submit" >add</button>
    <ul id="listwithbeer"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand where you populate beersArray, it's always empty. Put it out of click handler, and keep sync with items in ul list

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code

- The array should be declared outside of the handler else every click will create a new handler
- The array should be populated with the input value, not with the value returned by `appendChild()`
- You can use `indexOf` to check whether the current value is present in the array

So

```js
var beersArray = [];
var submitBier = document.getElementById("submitbeer");
var beer = document.getElementById("favobeer");
var beerList = document.getElementById("listwithbeer");
submitBier.addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();


  var value = beer.value.trim();

  if (beersArray.indexOf(value) == -1) {
    var beerLi = document.createElement("LI");
    var BeerName = document.createTextNode(value);
    beerLi.appendChild(BeerName);
    beerList.appendChild(beerLi);
    beersArray.push(value);
  } else {
    alert("This beer is already in the list");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="beers">
  <h1 id="vraagnaam">add your favourite beers</h1>
  <input type="text" id="favobeer" value="" />
  <button id="submitbeer" type="submit" value="Submit">add</button>
  <ul id="listwithbeer"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2nd for loop won't be necessary if you are looping through the same array.

The correct way to putting in a 'if-else' statement within a for loop can be done as follows:

```
for (var j = 0; j < beersArray.length; j++) {

    // A If-conditional statement to short-circuit existing beer list
    if (beersArray[j] === beer.value) alert ('This beer is already in the list')

    // Core Logic
    beersArray[j].className = 'beer';
    beerLi.appendChild(BeerName);
    beerList.appendChild(beerLi);
    beersArray.push(beerList.appendChild(beerLi));
}
```